# Editing the shape_length field in a gdb file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing

I spotted two mistakes in my file (see objectid = 395), as seen in the photo. I know what the values are meant to be, and I can edit the length(km) variable in ArcMap, but I am unable to edit the shape_length variable. How then can I fix the incorrect observation, and have the correct file?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you do not have a shapefile at all. The `OBJECTID` column only exists in a file geodatabase or other database formats. A shapefile would have a `FID` column.

Within the file geodatabase you get the column length as an geometry-attribute that is always there. It is a fundamental value of your geometry and in contrast to the shapefile you don't need to update. You can't change it without changing the geometry of the feature.

But it looks like that one of your features has a incorrect geometry. Can you select the feature with the wrong entry and zoom to it? It should not be visible when the entry is broken. But why this happened is the main problem. `1.#INF` means that the value is too large for the data-type. As the data-type is double which allows huge numbers there is something really wrong.

Comment: An answer should answer the question, not ask for further information.  Your question "Can you select the feature with the wrong entry and zoom to it?" should be asked as a comment.

Comment: quick and dirty copy and paste the broken feature keep the new, delete the old fid 395. maybe the shape_length will update itself properly

Comment: My apologies, I have shown you a picture of a gdb file here.

Comment: @Kelly have you tried @ gomapping's suggestion?

Comment: yes but the paste did not work

Comment: Did you run a geometry check or a Repair Geometry on a copy?

Comment: It would not run, it said that the geometry is out of bounds. I guess it is because the error in the data plots a line that is off of the shape file of the country ( in this case it places the road network in the water)